# How to modify computed font-size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I am trying to change the font size of a text so that it fits the dimension of a dynamic div.

I have found some jquery code which fits the bill, however I can't use jquery in my code and need to convert it into vanilla javascript.

When I run the converted code I receive this error:
'Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'font-size' property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the 'font-size' property is read-only.'

This is the original jQuery codes I need to convert:

```
elements = $('.resize')
el = elements[_i]
```

and:

```
resizeText = function () {
    var elNewFontSize
    elNewFontSize = (parseInt($(el).css('font-size').slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px'
    return $(el).css('font-size', elNewFontSize)
  }
```

And this is my conversion on:

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('resize')
el = elements[_i]
```

and:

```
resizeText = function () {
    var elNewFontSize
    elNewFontSize = (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize.slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px'
    window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize = elNewFontSize
    return elNewFontSize
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add ;  to line endings first. (probably a mistake copying)

Comment: @Mikes3ds I'm coding in Vue2.0 and somehow ending my JS with ; generates a syntax error.

Comment: @Mikes3ds Are you saying semicolons are required to make the code work?

Comment: Nope, just noticed, not familiar with the VUE js framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the new size to the element's `style.fontSize` property, and not the computed value that you get from window.getComputedStyle(), e.g.

```
el.style.fontSize = elNewFontSize;
```

--

As an aside, and not directly related, there is no reason to have the variable name twice, you can initialize it with the declaration, i.e. instead of:

```
var elNewFontSize
elNewFontSize = ...
```

Simply write

```
var elNewFontSize = ...
```

Comment: thank you @isapir. on a side note I am running the code both on window.onload and on window.onresize. However on resize doesn't work. Why this is happening?

Comment: @Marcello is it on a public page where we can see it?  I'm sure that there's a simple explanation

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not public. will try to reproduce it in a pen and repost.